# The VSCode debug not working when want to see a breakpoint

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

hello I have a problem when debugging in unity .
sorry I really no idea to descript this situation,
but this problem suffered me for a long time.

1.just coding something like this

[coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVAti.png)

2. running unity
3. start debug in vscode
4. add break point like this

[add breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS2Bk.png)

5. soon, the unity will stopped, but in vsc , that line will not be highlighted,
   and can not go to next step or prev bug just stop debug.

[debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tu2j.png)

can anyone help me ? I'v been troubled for half-year,
every time want to see the inside the of sth, I can only use Deubg.Log and log it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using unity debugger extension?
follow these steps in setting up the debugger:
[Unity Development with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity)

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. : ) 
I'm using the unity debugger extension and OmniSharp with Net Core 3.1.

Comment: After search others similar issues. I finally found one thing is different between my project and new one . The Scripting Runtime Version is too old for new VsCode. After I upgraded it, it fixed. still thanks alot.